# Нужна ли запятая перед «как» в данном примере?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, как

Нужна ли запятая перед "как" в данном предложении?

*Азиаты платили грекам **как** более слабой стороне, чтобы соперники в заочных и очных поединках истощали друг друга.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запятая не нужна.

Это отождествление. Розенталь: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=147

В таком случае по смыслу можно подставить слово "являясь":
*Азиаты платили грекам, которые **являлись** более слабой стороной, чтобы соперники в заочных и очных поединках истощали друг друга.*

Запятая ставится при сравнении. Тогда можно подставить "как будто" или "как и". Но оно вообще сюда **не подходит** по смыслу:
*Азиаты платили грекам, **как будто** более слабой стороне, чтобы соперники в заочных и очных поединках истощали друг друга.

Азиаты платили грекам, **как и** более слабой стороне, чтобы соперники в заочных и очных поединках истощали друг друга.*